# I am using this code on popup window.in this code data insert into database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am using this code on popup window.in this code data insert into database,validation is work and success message is also display but i want display error message on pop up and reset the form Pls help me how to fix this...

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#insert").click(function(){

    var OPRID=$("#OPRID").val();
    var OPRNAME=$("#OPRNAME").val();
    var OPERPSWD=$("#OPERPSWD").val();
    var OPRTYPE=$("#OPRTYPE").val();
    var PHONENO=$("#PHONENO").val();
    var ACCTLOCK=$("#ACCTLOCK").val();
    var ENCRYPTED=$("#ENCRYPTED").val();

   if (OPRID==null || OPRID=="")
   {
    alert("Operator Id must be filled out");
    return false;
    }
    if (OPRNAME==null || OPRNAME=="")
   {
    alert("Operator Name must be filled out");
    return false;
    }
    if (OPERPSWD==null || OPERPSWD=="")
     {
   alert("Password must be filled out");
   return false;
     }
   if (OPRTYPE==null || OPRTYPE=="")
   {
   alert("Operator Type must be filled out");
   return false;
    }
  if (PHONENO==null || PHONENO=="")
   {
   alert("Phone Number must be filled out");
    return false;
     }
  else{

  $.post('insert_opr.php', 
    {OPRID: OPRID,OPRNAME: OPRNAME,OPERPSWD: OPERPSWD, OPRTYPE:       
    OPRTYPE,PHONENO:PHONENO,ACCTLOCK:ACCTLOCK,ENCRYPTED:ENCRYPTED},

   function(data){
   $("#message").html(data);
   $("#message").hide();
    $("#message").show().fadeOut(5000);                       
    $('#myForm')[0].reset();

    });
   }
  return false;
  });
  });
```

Comment: What is actually happening now? Do you get an error? Or does it submit the from right away? What do you need exactly? Because you're using jquery now, and you will need PHP to update the database. You can make an AJAX call for this: `$.ajax({type: 'post',url: path/to/url, data: { data: here, maybe: 2params, or: more }})`

Comment: data insert into database,validation is work and success message is also display but i want display error message

Comment: #message (id) show the display messge

Comment: can you explain me..
how to use this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use associative array and convert the same to json object and return json object from function. Also in ajax post method you have to add one more argument as below

```
$.post('insert_opr.php', 
{OPRID: OPRID,OPRNAME: OPRNAME,OPERPSWD: OPERPSWD, OPRTYPE:       
OPRTYPE,PHONENO:PHONENO,ACCTLOCK:ACCTLOCK,ENCRYPTED:ENCRYPTED},

function(data){
if(data.status == "error")
{
$("#message").html(data.message);
$("#message").hide();
$("#message").show().fadeOut(5000);                       
$('#myForm')[0].reset();
}
if(data.status == "success")
{
 //your success code goes here
}
}, 'json');
```

You can return the json object as follows :

```
$data = array( 'status' => 'error' , 'message'  => 'error message' );
echo json_encode($data);
```

Likewise you can return success message with status as success.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little modification is needed in else section.Here it goes.

```
else{
$.post('insert_opr.php', 
        {OPRID: OPRID,OPRNAME: OPRNAME,OPERPSWD: OPERPSWD, OPRTYPE:       
        OPRTYPE,PHONENO:PHONENO,ACCTLOCK:ACCTLOCK,ENCRYPTED:ENCRYPTED},

       function(data,status){

       if(status=="success")
       { 
       $("#message").html(data);
       $("#message").hide();
        $("#message").show().fadeOut(5000);                       
        $('#myForm')[0].reset();
       }

      else
      { 
      $("#message").html("<b>Your error message here</b>");

      }
   });
}
```

That should do the trick. Cheers